# Setting up my php.ini

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu

Trying to edit my `php.ini` file

Executed:

```
vi /etc/php5/php.ini
```

but when i try to search

```
sendmail_path =
```

server response is

> E486: Pattern not found: sendmail_path =

So i tried directly executing

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/.msmtp_php --logfile /var/log/msmtp.log -a gmail -t"
```

response is: `/etc/php5/php.ini" E212: Can't open file for writing`

here is my version of php and ubuntu:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"

PHP version
PHP 7.0.14 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2016 18:11:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
```

I am not sure if my commands are right.

Comment: iam trying to follow the steps here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function#common-errors , i can already send mail through command line but beyond that starting with the chown command i am not sure if the commands i am inputting are correct

Comment: i want to replace sendmail_path

Comment: sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/.msmtp_php --logfile /var/log/msmtp.log -a gmail -t"